# Weird IE8 internal [[ class ]] attribute behavior

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, internet-explorer-8, local-storage

I recently had some trouble with IE8 (I don't know about 9 at this point) with reading and comparing the value of some `[[Class]]` properties. Actually it's only in the case for the `localStorage` object.

I'm using a method like this

```
var ToStr = Object.prototype.toString;
Object.type = function _type( obj ) {
    var res = ToStr.call( obj ).split( ' ' )[ 1 ].replace( ']', '' );

    if( obj === window ) {
        res = 'Window';
    }
    else if( res === 'Window' || res === 'Global' ) {
        res = 'Undefined';
    }
    else if( res.indexOf( 'HTML' ) === 0 ) { 
        res = 'Node';
    }

    return ( res );
};
```

This method will return this values for instance:

```
var foo = { },
    bar = [ ],
    num = 52,
    win = window;

Object.type( foo ) === 'Object'; // true
Object.type( bar ) === 'Array'; // true
Object.type( num ) === 'Number'; // true
Object.type( win ) === 'Window'; // true
```

That works of course, in all browsers I'm aware of by simply checking that `[[Class]]` property from an object itself. Now, I'm calling this method on the `localStorage` object

```
Object.type( win.localStorage ) === 'Storage' // true (not in IE8)
```

IE8 just returns `Object` here. However, that is not the actuall problem, the problem happens when you try to compare the `localStorage` object with the `window` object. As you can see, I'm checking if the passed in argument is the current `window` object

```
if( obj === window ) { }
```

If `obj` now is the `window.localStorage` object, this will end up in an error

```
"Class does not support automation"
```

This only happens if you try to compare `localStorage` with `window`, you can compare it against anything else without any trouble. Is this just another bug or can I workaround this issue somehow ?

I guess basically my question is:

**How do you know in IE8 (possibly IE9 too) if you're dealing with the `localStorage` object?**

The last thing I want to do is to inner-wrap the whole method with a `try-catch` because it gets called fairly often.

To entirely confuse me here it comes: When you do a `console.log( obj )` in IE8's console it returns you `[object Storage]` (nice!) but if you call `Object.prototype.toString.call( obj )` it returns `[object Object]`. Same goes for `typeof obj`, will return `object`.

Second question:

**How does the IE8 `console` print out the correct `[[Class]]` ?**

Comment: FYI: I checked, and IE9 works as expected, and shows neither issue.

Comment: Just a wild guess based on some random thing in my memory: is it any different if you test against `window.window` instead of just `window`? (Or maybe `window.self`?)

Comment: @Pointy: just tried, same error in IE8 (if that would have worked I was gonna ragequit IE forever btw)

Comment: OK.  Well I just recalled that the `window` reference in some version of IE is not the same as `window.window`.  Instead of coding in `try ... catch` always, you could create the function dynamically and test in the function that creates it, resulting in an IE8 version *with* `try ... catch` and a normal version otherwise.

Comment: @Pointy: yes I could do that. I don't like it anyway. I'm still hoping there is some magic property or whatever that can tell you in-code if it is the `localStorage` object. the `console` can do it...

Comment: The name of that internal property is `[[Class]]`, not `[[cclass]]`...

Comment: Hm, I get no errors in my IE when I call `Object.type( window.localStorage )`  (I tried in IE7, IE8 and IE9, modes)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: what about calling `window.localStorage === window` in IE8 ?

Comment: @jAndy I merely get `false`. I get this result in all modes. (I run this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/4yNXL/ - and switch the Browser/Document mode to IE7/IE8/IE9 via the F12 tools.)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I guess you're using IE9 then.. as it turns out this bevahior is not reproducible with IE9 (even in other modes). That error only occurs in IE8.

Comment: I am not 100% sure about what I am going to say. It is just a guess. But error message with the word "automation" in it usually come from an object which is not native JavaScript in IE. Since IE8 is less compliance than IE9, may be the 'LocalStorage' object is in fact backed by ActiveX which cause this kind of problem. May be it is like the XmlHttpRequest in IE7? Can any one confirm this by turning off IE8 ActiveX and test? I don't have IE8 with me any more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a way to work around the IE8 behavior using an implicit `toString()` operation and the ECMAScript spec explains why the work-around makes sense.  The implicit `toString()` is this:

```
"" + window.localStorage
```

This is implicitly forcing a call to the object's internal `toString()` method and, in IE, this will return the desired form you want `[object Storage]` and you can get your code to work without special casing `window.localStorage`.

So, I was looking for the minimal risk way to incorporate this into your existing code.  The approach chosen was to get the type that same way you use to get it and if and only if it returns a generic "Object" type, then see if there is a better name available with the new method.  So, all things that used to work just fine will continue to work the way they did and we might find a better name for some objects (like `window.localStorage`) that used to return a generic "Object" name.  The one other change is that I felt less confident about the exact type of return we might get from the `"" + obj` construct so I wanted a parsing method that wouldn't throw an error on unexpected data so I switched to a regex from the split/replace method you were using.  The regex also enforces that it's really the `[object Type]` format too which seems desirable.

Then, to protect against the odd issue of comparing `localStorage === window` and getting an error, you can add a type check (duck typing) that a non-window like object would not pass and this will filter out the `localStorage` issue and any other objects with the same issue.  In this particular case, I make sure the type of the object is `"object"` and that it has a property named `setInterval`.  We could have selected any well known, well supported property of the `window` object that is unlikely to be on any other object.  In this case, I use `setInterval` because that's the same test that jQuery uses when it wants to know if an object is a window.  Note, I also changed the code to not explicitly compare to `window` at all because there can be more than one `window` object (frames, iframes, popups, etc...) so this way, it will return "Window" for any window object.

Here's the code:

```
Object.type = function _type( obj ) {

    function parseType(str) {
        var split = str.split(" ");
        if (split.length > 1) {
            return(split[1].slice(0, -1));
        }
        return("");
    }

    var res = parseType(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj));

    // if type is generic, see if we can get a better name
    if (res === "Object") {
        res = parseType("" + obj);
        if (!res) {
            res = "Object";
        }
    }
    // protect against errors when comparing some objects vs. the window object
    if(typeof obj === "object" && "setInterval" in obj) {
        res = 'Window';
    }
    else if( res === 'Window' || res === 'Global' ) {
        res = 'Undefined';
    }
    else if( res.indexOf( 'HTML' ) === 0 ) { 
        res = 'Node';
    }

    return ( res );
};
```

See a demo with various test cases here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/euBWV

The desired value of `"[object Storage]"` that you were after in order to parse out the "Storage" class name comes from the internal `[[Class]]` property as defined in the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).  In section 8.6.2, the spec defines specific Class names for `"Arguments", "Array",  "Boolean",  "Date",  "Error",  "Function",  "JSON",  "Math",  "Number",  "Object", "RegExp", and "String"`.  It does not define Class names for host objects like `localStorage` so that is either left to individual browsers or is found in some other spec document.

Further, the spec says this about `[[Class]]`:

> The value of a [[Class]] internal property is used internally to
>   distinguish different  kinds of objects. Note that this specification
>   does not provide any means for a program to access that value except
>   through Object.prototype.toString (see 15.2.4.2).

And, it is in 15.2.4.2 that we find the specification for generating the output like `[object Array]` or `[object String]` by using the `[[Class]` as the second word.

So, `Object.prototype.toString` is how it is supposed to work.  Obviously IE8 has bugs in this regard for the `localStorage` object.  We can't know inside of IE8 whether `toString()` is not using `[[Class]]` or whether `[[Class]]` is not set properly.  In any case, it appears that `console.log()` in IE8 is not directly using `Object.prototype.toString()` because it generates a different result.

The behavior of the `"" + obj` work-around is more complicated to understand.  The spec describes how a type coercion of an object to a string is supposed to work.  It's a bit complicated to follow the thread all the way through the spec as one part depends upon another which depends upon another and so on.  But, in the end, it executes internal methods `ToString(ToPrimitive(input argument, hint String))` and apparently in IE8, `ToPrimitive` when passed a hint that we want a string is giving us the actual class name that `Object.prototype.toString()` is not.  There is a path through the spec that winds through `[[DefaultValue]]` which may be how this happens in IE8, but since we already know IE8 didn't follow the first part of the spec and it wasn't generally good at following the spec anyway, it's not a valid assumption to assume that it follows the spec in this regard.  In the end, we just know that a type coercion to string in IE8 ends up giving us the `[[Class]]` that we wanted.

As an interesting test, I tried my test suite in the Chrome browser running all the test cases that are objects through the `"" + obj` work-around (normally the code only uses that path when `Object.prototype.toString()` doesn't return a name other than `"Object"`.  It works for everything except an array.  I think this means that the `[[DefaultValue]]` for objects is generally `[[Class]]` (unless the object type decides it has a better default value which `Array` apparently does).  So, I think we have confirmation that the work-around that fixes IE8 is actually supposed to work per the spec.  So, not only is it a work-around for IE8, but it's an alternate path to get at the `[[Class]]` name if the object type doesn't implement a different default value.

So, really what this new code I've proposed is doing via the spec is this pseudo code:

1. Try to get at the internal variable `[[Class]]` using `Object.prototype.toString()`
2. If that gives us something other than `"Object"` then, use it
3. Otherwise, use `"" + obj` to try to get at the string version of `[[DefaultValue]]`
4. If that returns something useful, use it
5. If we still don't have something more useful than `"Object"`, then just return `"Object"`

Comment: Added info from the ECMAScript spec about the `[object Storage]` format that we were pursuing.

Comment: wow, thanks for the effort digging into the ES spec. I can't test it right now, but if the implicit cast/call really works in IE8, it'll be pretty neat. However, I don't love to bloat the `.type` method, especially with `regex` and more functions for performance reasons. Anyway, big +1 and the bounty is yours. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome to replace the regex.  Your method wasn't very safe because if it got unexpected input with no spaces, it would throw an exception which is why I did something different.  Yours could be made safer without a regex if you want with a little checking of the input.  There's hardly any bloat here other than the regex.  The only extra code path is when the type returns "Object" in which case it tries the cast to see if there's another way to get a meaningful type.  And, the `window` comparison is now safe and works for all window objects not just the global object.

Comment: the regex call itself seems to be a showstopper. I didn't benchmark it, but I'm pretty sure the regex is much slower. But I'll use the rest.

Comment: @jAndy - OK, I removed the regex and used something that's probably even faster than what you had.

Comment: I'm just back in the office (windows system) and checked that `"" + localStorage;` line, but my IE8 returns `[object]` ?

Comment: @jAndy - at first I was discouraged by your news, but when I run it on a genuine IE8 instance here, it works just fine as you can see in this screenshot: http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/i-VwpGkHz/0/XL/i-VwpGkHz-XL.png so something else must be going on in your sitaution.  It looks to me like this concept can be made to work in IE8.

Comment: @jAndy - In fact, when I look some debug output from [my jsFiddle with some extra logging put in](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/euBWV/96/), I see that this new technique in IE8 is coming up with improved names for not only "Storage", but also "Window", "HTMLDocument", "HTMLBodyElement" and any other HTML DOM object.  This seems to reinforce that this new code path is useful for getting a better name for a bunch of objects and `localStorage` is just one such object improved by this technique.

Comment: yea .. ultra weird behavior. On the default IE8 startpage, I get that `[object]` return when calling `"" + localStorage` in the internal console (F12). As soon I redirect to any other page, I get `[object Storage]`. wtf.....

Answer (score 3):

You wrote:

> This only happens if you try to compare `localStorage` with `window`, you can compare it against anything else without any trouble.

Then why don't you do so?

```
var ToStr = Object.prototype.toString; 
Object.type = function _type( obj ) { 
    if ( window.localStorage && obj === window.localStorage )
        return 'Storage';
    if ( obj === window ) 
        return 'Window'; 
    var res = ToStr.call( obj ).split( ' ' )[ 1 ].replace( ']', '' ); 
    if ( res === 'Window' || res === 'Global' ) { 
        return 'Undefined'; 
    if ( res.indexOf( 'HTML' ) === 0 ) {  
        return 'Node'; 
    return res; 
};
```

Addition to respond to the questions directly:

1. "... or can I workaround this issue somehow ?": You cannot. If the browser has a bug comparing two special values, you cannot fix this in javascript code....
2. "How do you know in IE8 (possibly IE9 too) if you're dealing with the localStorage object?" You check, if you are dealing with it, by simply comparing `obj === window.localStorage`. It cannot get any simpler than that, can it?
3. "How does the IE8 console print out the correct [[Class]] ?" Internal function have a very different kind of access to those objects, than javascript has... You cannot do the same things there.

Regards,
  Steffen

Comment: of course I could do something like that, but its not a solution in my opinion. I don't want to have a special comparison because of one browser freaking out and all other browsers treat `Storage` as a type

Comment: @jAndy - this is what you do to deal with bugs in old browsers.  There's absolutely nothing wrong with adding a special case for localStorage that makes IE8 work properly.  If you can find a work-around that doesn't require this, all the more power to you, but in the absence of that, this answer makes sense to me.  IE8 is old and buggy.  Personally, I'd spend as little time as I could finding a solution for it.

Comment: @jfriend00: I appreciate the suggestions and you might be right, but since this reply doesn't answer any of my questions, which will get rewarded with a bounty, I'd be rather unhappy to see this answer get that bounty.

Comment: It's correct that I didn't reply directly to the answers in the question, which I now added. However, I am not even interested in the bounty, so wait for an answer that suites you more. However, if there is no such answer AND the bounty time is over AND you use my approach, accept it then or add you own solution an accept that. Please don't just leave the message open, because I think there is nothing open to discuss or solve. (There simply is no way to work around a special bug without adding special workaround code.)

Comment: @SteffenHeil: "There simply is no way to work around a special bug", you are sure about that or you just guessing? If somebody can explain the behavior there might be a better/real workaround

Answer (score 1):

Feature detection should be used (see below) to avoid failed attempts to access `localStorage` [due to browser policies etc.](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute)

As for IE8-specific issue, could you confirm that the page is being *served* rather than opened locally? i.e. the URL is `http://localhost/hello.html` rather than `file:///C:/somefolder/hello.html` IE8 doesn't allow `localStorage` for files opened locally, although no official documentation could be found to back this (but there's [this](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/143) and [this](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/03/10/using-html5-web-storage-for-interprocess-communication.aspx) :) Also, possibly worth checking that you're not running the browser in IE7 mode.

In case your code above is supposed to *detect feature availability* rather than something else entirely, it would be an option to use something like [the following](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/localstorage-pattern):

```
// Feature test
var hasStorage = (function() {
  try {
    localStorage.setItem(mod, mod);
    localStorage.removeItem(mod);
    return true;
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty at all.  The only way I could get the string `"[object Storage]"` was by using the following code:

```
obj.constructor.toString();
```

For any native constructor, the output—and the expected output in other browsers—is a string representation of a native function.  However, we're talking about host objects here, where different rules apply entirely.  Interestingly, despite all its improvements to the DOM, IE 9 gives the same result.

It's not an entirely resilient solution, but it's the only solution I could find in the short time I had to take a look at the problem.

---

It seems there's a discrepancy between IE 8 and IE 9's IE 8 document mode and `localStorage.constructor` doesn't actually exist in the former.  In that case, I don't think there's another viable solution.  Duck typing doesn't seem like it would be effective as all of the `localStorage` object's property names are somewhat generic.  You could just use

```
window.localStorage === obj
```

But I'm not sure of IE 8's behaviour when trying to override native properties of the window object (if it doesn't allow it, then you may be OK).

Comment: In my IE9, `Object.prototype.toString.call( window.localStorage )` does return `[object Storage]`... (in IE8 and IE7 mode, I get `[object Object]`)

Comment: `window.localStorage.constructor === undefined` in my IE8 here ?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: yes, I was merely drawing attention to the fact that `localStorage.constructor.toString()` doesn't return a string representation of a native function like other browsers, even in IE 9.  As you said, the normal method of returning an object's internal `[[Class]]` attribute works as expected in IE 9, so shouldn't may not be an issue.

Comment: I wrote a comment on the question just now suggesting that the localStroage property may be backed by ActiveX (i.e. not native JavaScript), it looks very likely that I am correct after I read the above comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a very weird `IE8` bug! (oh what do I love IE)!

As stated in the comments for `IE8` browsers there is but one solution in my opinion:

```
typeof obj === "object" && obj.constructor.toString() === "[object Storage]"
```

Be sure the current browser is IE8 before checking, doesn't work otherwise, not even in other versions of IE!

P.S. Great example of how compatible IE is with its 'siblings'!