# Detecting localStorage v sessionStorage objects in different browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dojo, cross-browser, local-storage

I'm writing a Javascript class that is able to use either localStorage or sessionStorage.  The selection of this is done on a class instance basis.

I have a method within this class, which receives the storage object as a parameter and runs an action  according to the storage type (ie. local v session).

Eg.

```
function myMethod(store){
    // store: object storageObject
    //        The storage object being used (either
    //        sessionStorage or localStorage).

    if(store === sessionStorage){
        return sessionAction(store)
    }else if(store === localStorage){
        return localAction(store)
    }

    return null;
}
```

This does not work in Internet Explorer 8, producing the error: "*Class doesn't support Automation*".  It seems to work in other browsers quite well.

I've tried to get the object type (via **Object.prototype.toString.call(*store*)**) and test against that but IE8 always reports [object Object] for this.  I managed to make some progress from the answer to Stackoverflow question: [Weird IE8 internal [[ class ]] attribute behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872067/weird-ie8-internal-class-attribute-behavior).  This workaround gave me [object Storage] in IE.

However, I still cannot detect between the different storage types.  Is there a simple methodology for detecting between the two types that works cross-browser?

I could rewrite it so the type has't to be supplied as a parameter to the method.  However, I'd rather reduce the simplicity of the API by allowing users to simply supply the storage object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go *aggressive* for the IE8 code branch (inspired by [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)):

**Compare storages:**

```
function storagesEqual(testStorage, webStorage) {
    try {
        return testStorage === webStorage;
    } catch (ex) {
        // IE8 code branch
        var testKey = "storage-test";
        var testValue = (new Date()).valueOf().toString();
        var result = false;

        try {
            webStorage.setItem(testKey, testValue);
            if(testStorage[testKey] === testValue) {
                webStorage.removeItem(testKey);
                result = true;
            }
        } finally {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Indetify storage type:**

```
function storageType(store) {

    var STORAGE_LOCAL = 'local';
    var STORAGE_SESSION = 'session';
    var STORAGE_UNKNOWN = 'unknown';

    var localStorage = window.localStorage;
    var sessionStorage = window.sessionStorage;

    if(storagesEqual(store, localStorage)) return STORAGE_LOCAL;
    if(storagesEqual(store, sessionStorage)) return STORAGE_SESSION;
    return STORAGE_UNKNOWN;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  Yes, the brute-force method is probably the only route if I want it to work as requested in IE8.  Think, I'm okay with this; the inefficiency is acceptable given that it will only affect about 5% of users.  These users are already experiencing significant inefficiency by using IE8, so in the grand scheme of thing it probably doesn't matter too much.  Also, that 5% is likely to reduce over time.